# GMSMarker icon ignored

Tags: ios, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I recently updated to latest google maps sdk for ios (1.4) and I had a custom marker that I was using as a cluster marker and display the number of markers inside that marker.

```
- (UIImage *)icon {

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:DEFAULT_ICON];
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.markersInCluster count]];

UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:font];

CGPoint point = CGPointMake((img.size.width - textSize.width) /2, (img.size.height - textSize.height) /2);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,img.size.width,img.size.height)];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, img.size.width, img.size.height);
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
[text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;

}
```

This was working as it should until the upgrade, now it seems that it only renders the image if this icon property is changed on GMSMarker init otherwise it shows the default marker.

Comment: Are you sure this is still an issue with higher versions of SDK? I tried similar to this code with 1.4.2 and it works just ok.

Comment: This issue was fixed... but sometimes when you move the default icons appear...